# sql lite vs IsolatedStorage (Windows Phone)

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I'm building an app that will grab a content from some CMS, and save it in the phone.

Usually I do that using IsolatedStorageSettings. Is there any reason why would I use the SQLlite instead?

Comment: database also get stored in iso storage only.

Comment: so, is there any point of using sqlite over IsolatedStorage?

Comment: you get all the advantages of a dbms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need to use SQLite; MS doesn't have direct support to SQLite. You can use SQLCE for your application instead. Simply the usage of Isolated Storage is not appreciable if you are using a huge chunk of structured data. Still you decide to use ISO for storing i am sure definitely you will face issue in future. Probably the areas like Tombstoning, FAS etc where yo may take a lots of time for saving your data to files